# Cannot access security panel from anydesk

Tags: 18.04

When I go to enable the security settings on anydesk, It asks for my password and then does nothing after.  I cannot set up unattended access, which is what I need to be able to work on that machine.  Any ideas?

Comment: did you fix this? I tried echo command still issue is the same

Answer (score 14):

This worked for me: Setting the password using the command line
https://support.anydesk.com/Command_Line_Interface

```
echo mynewpassword | sudo anydesk --set-password
```

Comment: also linux mint :)

Answer (score 5):

the  `echo password | sudo anydesk --set-password` fix does work but you need to completely restart `anydesk` for it to take place.

To do that, use :

```
ps -aux | grep anydesk
```

and kill all `anydesk` leftover processes, then restart `anydesk`.

Comment: I didn't need to restart it, it worked immediately for me

Answer (score 3):

Based on [@padje answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1197481/829702), I suggest you this one-line command for restarting completely `anydesk` :

```
kill $(ps -aux | grep anydesk | awk '{print $2}') | anydesk --service
```

Explanation :

- `ps -aux` would show every active processes
- `grep anydesk` would find every `anydesk` processes running, displayed into `ps` output
- `awk '{print $2}'` would take the PID column (which is the 2nd)
- `kill` closed every commands refered to PIDs given by combinaison of 3 previous command (`ps` + `grep` + `awk`). You can also add the `-9` option to `kill`, to force them to close (notably when they are totally frozed)
- `anydesk --service` would start again `anydesk` (correct me in comment if I do a mistake here

NB : this type of command line can be used for some software, when you want to restart them manually (and when you can't use `service <software_command> restart`)

Comment: Just `sudo kill $(ps -aux | grep anydesk | awk '{print $2}') | anydesk --service` then run anydesk again. It's enough.

Comment: and you can do it automatically by editing anydesk systemd service file, `sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/anydesk.service`. put above line after to the ExecStart original line. like this `ExecStart=/usr/bin/anydesk --service | sudo kill $(ps -aux | grep anydesk | awk '{print $2}') | /usr/bin/anydesk --service`

Answer (score 2):

From commandline use  `anydesk-global-settings` where you are able to do the settings using the interface.

Answer (score 0):

Salut!
If you have installed AnyDesk using Software Manager then it runs in a container called "flatpak", you can find the command in the link where you start AnyDesk and it looks like this:

```
/usr/bin/flatpak run --branch=stable --arch=x86_64 --command=anydesk com.anydesk.Anydesk
```

To solve the problem uninstall AnyDesk using Software Manager and then download and install [AnyDesk for Linux](https://anydesk.com/en/downloads/linux).

AnyDesk from Software Manager works perfectly for outbound connections and does not work at all for incoming connections.

If the problem is "flatpak" you can use sudo comand:

```
sudo /usr/bin/flatpak run --branch=stable --arch=x86_64 --command=anydesk com.anydesk.Anydesk
```