# How can I enable AnyDesk Unattended Login on i3WM?

Tags: i3-wm, anydesk

**Please note:** parts of this question comes from [my opened thread on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/i3wm/comments/hfg8xo/how_can_i_use_anydesk_unattended_login_in_i3wm/).

**Please also note:** The expected solution should be related to **AnyDesk and i3WM**, no "NoMachine", VNC, TeamViewer or any other remote desktop solutions. Thanks for understanding.

## The problem

I am an i3wm user and I'd like to use AnyDesk unattended login but I can't enable it without super user privileges via `sudo`.

I mean, if I run `sudo anydesk` it works and allow me to do the changes needed to allow the unattended login but once I close anydesk, it does not work for a normal user session.

When I run `anydesk` as a normal user, all the `Security options` are greyed out and I can't unlock it by clicking on the "`Unlock Security Settings`" link.

[image]

### What have I tried

I have seen this question, [Cannot access security panel from anydesk](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1118266/cannot-access-security-panel-from-anydesk) and while the provided answers may help a lot, I am facing a different issue.

Once I use [this suggested solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/1147612/9598):

```
echo mynewpassword | sudo anydesk --set-password
```

My terminal responds with:

```
Setting the password requires administrator privileges and an installed service.
```

I have also tried with the answers to this question: [Anydesk on Ubuntu does not save Unattended Access Security Setting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1209964/anydesk-on-ubuntu-does-not-save-unattended-access-security-setting) with similar results.

I have read there's something related to polkit or policykit, which I don't have on my i3WM system and that's why I can't run graphic super user requests a la `gksudo`.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, after doing some research on my own, both on the net and this site, I got into the `lxpolkit` tool, among a bunch of other stuff related to policy kit and these things.

Installing `lxpolkit` now provides a Graphic User Interface to insert the proper elevated user password in order to gain access to the privileges I couldn't reach before.

Now, everytime I wish to commit some changes to the "Security Options" from within AnyDesk's main window, I get a small window asking for the user's password, after which I can change everything.

[image]

Somehow, and having in consideration that this tool is designed for `LXDE`, this is the only solution working for me on `i3WM`. Maybe someone wish to add some explanation about?

As for me, I am pleased with the solution, which I write here just in case somebody else is trying to find a solution.

BTW: This tool now also allow me to elevate the user privileges for other tools like `code`/`codium` when trying to edit the `/var/www/html/` public files, which are read with ease but needs to run elevated privileges to write'm down on disk again.